# Matching not working as expected in Name-based Virtual Host in Apache

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost

When I run httpd -S, it outputs the following:

```
VirtualHost configuration:
*:443                  is a NameVirtualHost
         default server www.example.com (/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:57)
         port 443 namevhost localhost (/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:57)
         port 443 namevhost www.example.com (/etc/httpd/conf.vh/example.conf:1)
                 alias example.com
```

Line 57 of `/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf`:

`<VirtualHost _default_:443>`

First lines of `/etc/httpd/conf.vh/example.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>

DocumentRoot "/var/www/www_example_com/"
ServerName www.example.com
ServerAlias example.com
```

However when I go to https://www.example.com it shows the  /var/www/html content instead of /var/var/www_example_com

I resolve www.example.com from client side using /etc/hosts and also on server and not using DNS because is a development server.

If I add `ServerName localhost` in `ssl.conf` it serves files in var/var/www_example_com but I would want to avoid to do that workaround.

Any idea why does it not match as I expected?

Comment: What messages do you get when you restart apache?

Comment: Did you run `httpd -S` before or after naming the `<VirtualHost>` in `ssl.conf`? It shows different names than in the published config: most notably the `<VirtualHost>` in `example.com` is called `www.example.com.ar`.

Comment: It was a typo: is really www.example.com